# Break the while stament and the code after it if the statement is fulfiled

Tags: java

I am trying to return the `routeList` if the distance is less than 15 and do not to  run the code after the while statement if that the case is. Currently the `routelist` is being overriden in the if statement. How can I reach that?

I appreciate any help.

```
    public ArrayList<Integer> detectRoute(double latD, double longD) {

        ArrayList<Integer> routeList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
       .
       .
       .
    PreparedStatement preparedLatLongName = con
                            .prepareStatement("SELECT lat, longi, name from stops");
                    ResultSet rsLLN = preparedLatLongName.executeQuery();

                    // ArrayList<Double> distanceHistory = new ArrayList<Double>();
                    List<StopItem> distanceHistory = new ArrayList<>();

                    while (rsLLN.next()) {
                        double latStop = rsLLN.getDouble("lat");
                        double lonStop = rsLLN.getDouble("longi");
                        String nameStop = rsLLN.getString("name");
                        double distStop = haversineDistance(latD, longD, latStop,
                                lonStop);
                        StopItem newItem = new StopItem(nameStop, distStop );
                        distanceHistory.add(newItem);


                        // TODO add the speed here.
                        if (distStop <= 15) {
                            routeList = getByStop(con, calendar, WDay, rsLLN);
                            break;
                        }

                    }
                    //Find the shortest distance and its related longi and lati
                    Collections.sort(distanceHistory);
                    double shortestDistance = distanceHistory.get(0).getStopDist();
                    String nameShortestDistance = distanceHistory.get(0).getNameStop();
       .        
       .
       .
       .
        return routeList;
}
```

Comment: can you explain your question clearly. should routerList be overwritten in the if block or not.

Comment: Yes it should be overwritten.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to even break the loop. Just replace the `break` with `return routeList`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `boolean` flag? Something like:

```
boolean flag = false;
while (rsLLN.next()) {
    // ...
    if (distStop <= 15) {
        routeList = getByStop(con, calendar, WDay, rsLLN);
        flag = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (!flag) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others indicated, you can just return your routeList instead of break.
Alternatively, if you want to execute code after the while (rather than return in the middle of it), there is a way to do that using labels (which you should avoid if you can).

```
someLabel:
  while (...) {
     ...
     if () {
        ...
        break someLabel;
     }
  }

 // the break sends execution to here
```